# Count an intersection where two dates match

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have several Role Playing dimensions that are FK's to the Date Dimension. How would I best count the intersection where a date from from Date Dimension matches the Date in a Role Playing Dimension?

In SQL it would be something like:

```
    Select  DimDate,
            COUNT(1)
    From    DimDateTable        D
    join    RolePlayingTable    R   on D.Date = R.Date
    Group by DimDate
```

I thought this would work:

```
    With
    Member  [Measures].[First Date In]      as
        (
        [Measures].[Account Count],
        [Sprocket Date].[Date].CurrentMember
        )
    Member  [Measures].[First Date Out]     as
        (
        [Measures].[Account Count],
        [Widget Date].[Date].CurrentMember
        )


    Select  
            {
            [Measures].[First Date In],
            [Measures].[First Date Out]
            } on 0,

            Non Empty
            [Dim Calendar].[Date].[Date] on 1

    From    [Cube-Bert]
```

But it only counts the intersecting points and not where the Sproket.Date = Calendar.Date

I also tried this, but it's not right either:

```
    with 
    Member  [Measures].[Count] as
        Sum(
            Exists(
                {[Sproket Date].[Date].[Date]},
                {[Dim Calendar].[Date].[Date]}
                )
            ,[Measures].[Account Count]
            )

    select  [Measures].[Count] on 0,
            Non Empty
            [Dim Calendar].[Date].members on 1
    from    [Cube-Bert]
```

Comment: The answer I ended up using was to add calculated fields in my DSV that were 0 and 1 flag columns based on the dates matching. I tried to use LinkMember function but was unsuccessful. I feel like I cheated, but withthe time constraints I am under I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I put the date matching logic into the DSV and produced a flag column in the fact table, 1 = true, 0 = false.